# Bug in safari toLocaleDateString between 2004/03/15 and 2004/04/04. Any other dates known?

Tags: ios, date, safari

I just stumbled in safari the toLocaleDateString returning date one day before for the dates between 2004/03/15 and 2004/04/04. Here is a clip from safari JS console demonstrating the problem:

```
> (new Date(2004,2,14))
< Sun Mar 14 2004 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)
> (new Date(2004,2,14)).toLocaleDateString()
< "March 14, 2004"
> (new Date(2004,2,15))
< Mon Mar 15 2004 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
> (new Date(2004,2,15)).toLocaleDateString()
< "March 14, 2004"
> (new Date(2004,3,4))
< Sun Apr 04 2004 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
> (new Date(2004,3,4)).toLocaleDateString()
< "April 3, 2004"
> (new Date(2004,3,5))
< Mon Apr 05 2004 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
> (new Date(2004,3,5)).toLocaleDateString()
< "April 5, 2004"
```

The problem present in both macos and ios versions.

While it is not fixed I can correct displaying dates in this interval manually. But maybe there are other such bad date intervals known, that would also need correction? What is so special about these particular dates?

[Edit] OK, running the following one liner in safari javascript console shows that there are in excess of 180 such intervals between years 1900 and 2100. So the question should be modified, what would be the best way to deal with this problem?

```
(function(){var from,last,now; for (var y=1900; y<2100;y++) for (var m=0;m<12;m++) for (var d=1;d<32;d++) { now = new Date(y,m,d); if (Date.parse(now.toLocaleDateString())!=Date.parse(now.toString())) {if (!from) from=now;} else if (from) {console.log(from.toDateString()+'-'+last.toDateString());from=null;}last=now;}})()
```

[EDIT 2] It turns out the bad intervals depend on time zone settings. Changing timezone on ios from GMT-5 to GMT+12 produced 200 intervals that are completely different. It looks like now I am looking for suggestions for replacement for toLocaleDateString in safari alltogether

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround - add an hour to the date. That is, changing Date(y,m,d) to Date(y,m,d,1) does not produce any output in above one0liner test.